# SQL Count(*) in C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, count

How can I implement a SQL query with a `Count(*)` in a lambda expression?

What I want is to convert a query like this:

```sql
SELECT SendType, 
    CASE WHEN Date IS NULL THEN
        'NEW'
    ELSE
        'NOT NEW'
    End Registry,
    Count(*) as TotalSent
FROM [dbo].[Sends]
WHERE Disabled = 0
GROUP BY 
    SendType, 
    Registry
```

to some lambda expression like this:

```
context.EnviosPendientes
    .Where(ep => ep.Disabled == false)                        
    .Select(ep => new {
        SendType = ep.SendType,
        Registry = ep.Date == null ? "NEW" : "NOT NEW"
    })
    .GroupBy(ep => new { ep.TipoEnvio, ep.TipoReg })
```

but I don't know how to include in the result select the `Count(*) as TotalSent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like:

```
.GroupBy(ep => new { ep.SendType, ep.Registry })
.Select(ep => new
{
    ep.Key.SendType,
    ep.Key.Registry,
    TotalSent = ep.Count()
});
```

The resulting `IEnumerable<>` will have three properties, `SendType`, `Registry`, `TotalSent`.